# Nonlinear model fit gaussian precision

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, precision-and-accuracy

I wanted to fit double gaussian but it doesn't work, it doesn't fit gaussian. The error I get:

[image: error]

Data:[data](https://ufile.io/e02o8bg5)  Here is code

```
peaks = {{398, 0.511}, {495, 0.662}, {819, 1.173}, {921, 1.332}}

lm = LinearModelFit[peaks, x, x]

co60pl1 = 
  Import[
   "/Users/co60_pl1_1200s.lst", "Table"];

nlmcopl1 = 
 NonlinearModelFit[
  Select[{lm[First[#]], Last[#]} & /@ co60pl1, 1 <= #[[1]] <= 1.5 &], 
  a3*E^(-((x - 1.173)^2/(2*b3^2))) + b3*x + c3 + 
   a4*E^(-((x - 1.332)^2/(2*b4^2))), {a3, b3, c3, a4, b4}, x, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very informative. What goes wrong? Do you get errors? Are you unhappy with the quality of the fit? Have you tried providing good initial guesses for the values of your fit parameters, rather than relying on the defaults?

Comment: @MarcoB I put guesses: `1.173, 1.332` but still I don't get doble gaussian fit.

Comment: We need to know what is `piki`

Comment: @JackLaVigne I've corrected the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of problems. The means that you are using, 1.173 and 1.332 are reasonable guesses, but I suggest letting `NonlinearModelFit` find those parameters. A big mistake is using the same parameter, `b3`, for the variance of the first Gaussian and the slope of the line. Another problem is that `NonlinearModelFit` is going to need some reasonable starting parameters for the model.

Here is a plot of your data.

```
co60pl1 = Import["co60_pl1_1200s.lst", "Table"];

ListPlot[co60pl1, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you use `peaks` to shift the x axis.

```
peaks = {{398, 0.511}, {495, 0.662}, {819, 1.173}, {921, 1.332}}

lm = LinearModelFit[peaks, x, x]
```

This enables us to create a new set of data with the x-axis shifted. I'll call it `shiftedData`.

```
shiftedData = {lm[First[#]], Last[#]} & /@ co60pl1;
```

Next step is to limit it to where x is between 1 and 1.5. For reason's I will explain later, I also created data limited between 1.07 and 1.5.

```
shiftedData1 = Select[shiftedData, 1 <= #[[1]] <= 1.5 &];
shiftedData2 = Select[shiftedData, 1.07 <= #[[1]] <= 1.5 &];
```

Below is a plot of these three data sets. Note that `shiftedData` is identical to `co60pl12` except with the x-axis shifted.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[shiftedData, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListPlot[shiftedData1, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListPlot[shiftedData2, PlotStyle -> Blue]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Initially I am going to use `shiftedData2` and try to fit two Gaussians to it ignoring the linear portion.

I use `Manipulate` to get parameter values that are in the ball park.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListPlot[shiftedData2, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Plot[a1*Exp[-(x - μ1)^2/(2*σ1^2)] + 
       a2*Exp[-(x - μ2)^2/(2*σ2^2)],
   {x, 1, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Black]
  ],
 {{a1, 220}, 100, 300},
 {{μ1, 1.14}, 1.1, 1.3},
 {{σ1, 0.05}, 0.02, 0.2},
 {{a2, 160}, 100, 300},
 {{μ2, 1.3}, 1.2, 1.4},
 {{σ2, 0.04}, 0.02, 0.2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now refine the parameters by using `NonlinearModelFit` and supply the `Manipulate` parameters as starting values.

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[
  shiftedData2,
  a1*Exp[-(x - μ1)^2/(2*σ1^2)] + 
  a2*Exp[-(x - μ2)^2/(2*σ2^2)],
  {
   {a1, 220},
   {μ1, 1.14},
   {σ1, 0.05},
   {a2, 160},
   {μ2, 1.3},
   {σ2, 0.04}
   },
  x
  ]

nlm2["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a1 -> 214.277, μ1 -> 1.13994, σ1 -> 0.0532518, 
    a2 -> 155.572, μ2 -> 1.29863, σ2 -> 0.037658} *)
```

Next use the `shiftedData1` and the parameters from `nlm2` and guess the slope and intercept for the line using `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListPlot[shiftedData1, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Plot[m x + b + a1*Exp[-(x - μ1)^2/(2*σ1^2)] + 
    a2*Exp[-(x - μ2)^2/(2*σ2^2)],
   {x, 1, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Black]
  ],
 {{m, -260}, -2000, 0},
 {{b, 330}, 0, 2000},
 {{a1, 214}, 100, 300},
 {{μ1, 1.14}, 1.1, 1.3},
 {{σ1, 0.053}, 0.02, 0.2},
 {{a2, 155}, 100, 300},
 {{μ2, 1.3}, 1.2, 1.4},
 {{σ2, 0.038}, 0.02, 0.2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Final refinement is to fit the linear and Gaussian using `NonlinearModelFit` and supplying it with reasonable starting values.

```
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[
  shiftedData1,
  m x + b + a1*Exp[-(x - μ1)^2/(2*σ1^2)] + 
   a2*Exp[-(x - μ2)^2/(2*σ2^2)],
  {
   {m, -260},
   {b, 330},
   {a1, 214},
   {μ1, 1.14},
   {σ1, 0.053},
   {a2, 160},
   {μ2, 1.3},
   {σ2, 0.038}
   },
  x
  ]

nlm1["BestFitParameters"]
(* {m -> -260.749, b -> 379.83, 
    a1 -> 139.05,  μ1 -> 1.14737, σ1 -> 0.0357556, 
    a2 -> 118.309, μ2 -> 1.29887, σ2 -> 0.0319747} *)
```

A plot of the `shiftedData1` and the model shows a reasonable fit (the line from `NonlinearModelFit` is superimposed in Gray).

```
With[
 {
  m = m /. nlm1["BestFitParameters"],
  b = b /. nlm1["BestFitParameters"]
  },
 Show[
  Plot[nlm1[x], {x, 1, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Black],
  Plot[m x + b, {x, 1, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Gray],
  ListPlot[shiftedData1, PlotStyle -> Red]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]