# Plotting data and fitting to a function

Tags: plotting, fitting, import

[image]

I have three sets of data. I would like to plot them in the same graph. Then plot the following fittings to the data. Any help is appreciated!

- f(v) = (v^2)*exp(-mv^2/2 kb T)
- f(v) = (v^3)*exp(-mv^2/2 kb T)

data1:

```
data = Import[
   "/Users/julissavelasquez/Box/1_Harrison Lab/03_Formic \
Acid/Wodtke_2021_Fig4C/Data_Total_Integrated_distribution.xlsx"];

hyperthermal = 
  Import["/Users/julissavelasquez/Box/1_Harrison Lab/03_Formic \
Acid/Wodtke_2021_Fig4C/Data_Hyperthermal_distribution.xlsx"];

Plot[data, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Hyperthermal data:

Data for copying/pasting is in the Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-tVwtRmt6UD3v67eMO0e5lws8wwZ6G3hLaZJkETSK0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Could you please include your data in a copy-paste-able form? Also include any Mathematica code that you have tried out so far as this is a stack site about the technical computing software called Mathematica and the associated Wolfram Language.

Comment: @Syed I believe my data was too much to add in as code. I included a Google Sheets link with the data there.

Comment: Right now, the provided link is asking me to log into my google account. Please make it an accessible 1-click download.

Comment: @Syed Sorry about that. Please try again.

Comment: The energy in your data is the same everywhere. Then explain better what you want to fit and wich column you want to plot against which column.

Comment: I'm realizing now I copied the same data in each cell. That is now corrected. I however have all extracted the ENERGY data instead of the VELOCITY data. My fitting is to compare the experimental velocity to the fitting.

Comment: Perhaps [258533](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258533/nonlinear-model-fit-gaussian-precision) will be of some help, if the data has a Gaussian profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = First[Import["~/Downloads/Data.xlsx", "SkipLines" -> 2]][[1 ;; -2]];

total = data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
hyper = data[[All, 3 ;; 4]]
thermal = data[[All, 5 ;; 6]]

ListLinePlot[{total, hyper, thermal},
 PlotLabels -> {"Total", "Hyper", "Thermal"},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

The fit is not good the model probably needs adjusting or I have misinterpreted it.

```
totalFit = NonlinearModelFit[total, (v^2)*Exp[-m v^2/(2 k bt)], {m, k, bt}, v]

Show[ListPlot[total], Plot[totalFit[x], {x, 0, 1.2}], Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/Data.xlsx", 
    "SkipLines" -> 2][[1]];
```

Eliminate any missing data

```
total = data[[All, 1 ;; 2]] /. {"", ""} :> Nothing;
```

In your model, `m/2 kb T` acts as a single constant. The split of any derived value into these separate factors is arbitrary. You also need an overall scale factor. Use the model `a*(v^n)*Exp[-c v^2]` with `n` being either `2` or `3`.

```
(totalFit2 = 
   NonlinearModelFit[total, a*(v^2)*Exp[-c v^2], {a, c}, v]) // Normal

(* 11.1953 E^(-4.6119 v^2) v^2 *)

(totalFit3 = 
   NonlinearModelFit[total, a*(v^3)*Exp[-c v^2], {a, c}, v]) // Normal

(* 37.2111 E^(-6.30875 v^2) v^3 *)

Legended[
 Show[
  ListLinePlot[total, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][3]],
  Plot[{totalFit2[x], totalFit3[x]}, {x, 0, 1.2}],
  Frame -> True],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], {v^2, v^3, "data"}],
  {0.8, 0.7}]]
```

[image]